Connect a DVD player to an iMac
I have a DVD player that I want to connect to an iMac M3. This is not the standard external-drive DVD player, but one that you'd normally hook up to a TV or similar; more a set-top box style. It's a Sony DVP-SR760H, with line outs for audio and video, and a female HDMI port.
Before I buy a usb C – (male) HDMI cable: will this work? Can I play DVDs through this player on my iMac?

Are you planning on investing in an HDMI capture card for the Mac? https://www.imore.com/best-mac-compatible-capture-cards it seems you’ll need a moderately priced HDMI capture and an inexpensive RCA capture and OBS software to combine the two signals unless you are sure audio comes over the HDMI output from the DVD player. HDCP if present on the signal will increase your costs dramatically to capture the video.

@bmike Not really; I'd just like to be able to watch the DVDs from the player on the iMac. So would a capture card be the only way to do this?

Yes - the cheap adapters are one way - video leaves the Mac

@bmike Thanks. I suspected something like that might be the case; I'll have a thought about and further look into the capture card idea.

Looks like we have an answer, then. I’ll post the inexpensive solution and more expensive one, too

The inexpensive solution is buy a display that accepts HDMI signals and avoid the expense and setup time of video capture hardware, audio capture hardware, mixing software and possibly capture software if your hardware doesn’t work natively with your version of  macOS.

https://obsproject.com/
https://www.imore.com/best-mac-compatible-capture-cards

Inexpensive HDMI adapters are for sending the signal out from the Mac and not bringing it back. Also, check your model of player and media - they may implement HDCP to prevent trivial recording of a DVD signal output into an unprotected digital format sent to a computer.
